# Illustrator: How to make a repetitive change to a path?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path

I'm one day into learning how to use Illustrator (though I've got some experience with paths in Photoshop, from 5 years back).  I want to take a simple, rectangular path and put tabs on the sides so that each rectangle fits together kind of like puzzle pieces.

There must be a nice, easy way to do this but I can't figure it out.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Draw a rectangle
- Choose `Object > Path > Split Into Grid...`
- Define the size of the pieces by altering the row and column settings for the grid
- Grab the **Shape Builder Tool**
- Click-drag to combine grid pieces
- <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd>-click to remove pieces.

[image: puzzle rectangle]

Comment: Yes! That is what I wanted to be doing!  What do you mean by "click-crag"?

Comment: Typo.. click-drag.

Comment: @Scott! Scott!! Scott!!!

Answer (score 1):

Well this worked, but it was kind of finicky.

I made a rectangular tab, using the dimensions to make sure that the tab was 1/6th the height of my path.  Copied this out 6 times, grouped the tabs, and copy/pasted the group so that there were tabs on either side of my path.  Aligning the tabs perfectly was a real pain, but eventually I got it.

[image]

Then I deleted every other tab.

[image]

And last, I was able to select all the tabs and my original path and use the Pathefinder->Exclude tool to produce the shape I wanted.

[image]

That's about as efficient as I can think of.  The biggest time sink was in the alignment.  In order for these to fit together they really need to be perfect.  I think the reason it took so long was a combination of my inexperience and poor snapping settings in IA.

Comment: You probably could have created one tab, aligned it with the top of the large square, and opt-shift-dragged it to create a second one that's in line with the first tab. Let the top of the second tab snap to the bottom of the first. Then select both tabs, opt-shift-drag down, and snap the top to the bottom of the first two. Repeat once more to end up with 6 tabs all left-aligned neatly and touching. Then just select all 6 tabs and scale them up to the bottom of the square. Then it's just a matter of selecting the three you wanted on the right, dragging them over, and using the Pathfinder tool.